# How to fix the error which "Modune 'amplify_api_ios' not found" in Xcode to build a app

Tags: ios, flutter, aws-amplify

"I have been developing an app in Flutter and using the Amplify module. However, when I attempted to build the iOS version for deployment, I encountered errors related to the Amplify module. I have already tried running 'flutter clean', but the problem persists. Can you please advise on what I should do?"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5Hly.png)

I tried to clean and rebuild like "flutter clean && flutter pub get"